How to Access Android Health Connect from .NET MAUI code
Does anyone have any tips for accessing Android Health Connect data from a .NET MAUI app? There does appear to be an Android.Health.Connect namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.health.connect?view=net-android-34.0 but I can't find anything on how to use it.
For example, I need to be able to get an instance of a HealthConnectClient before I can read any fitness data. How would I instantiate that? https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-connect/develop/get-started
Any help would be much appreciated.

Platform code can be invoked from cross-platform code by using conditional compilation, or by using partial classes and partial methods.
So, you can call the android api on android platform, and then invoke the android code from the cross-platform code.
For more information, you can check document: Invoke platform code.
And you can also check the official sample here:
.NET MAUI - Invoke platform code.

Thanks Jessie for your prompt answer. I understand about conditional compilation and using partial classes/methods. My question is more about how to make the specific calls for Health Connect. For example, I need to get an instance of a HealthConnectClient and then call methods on that object such as aggregate to retrieve step data. I don't know how to get the HealthConnectClient object from .NET.

It looks like that the specific type HealthConnectClient is not part of the main Android SDK currently. And if you check the android document Health Connect, you will find that we need to reference androidx.health.connect:connect-client:1.1.0-alpha02 package.  But I haven't found that there is a binding for that package at this time.
And that package is still in alpha.  So, you need to bind it yourself currently.

Thanks Jessie. Guess I'll have to investigate how to create binding :)

Waiting for your good news. :)

@SteveMason Hi Steve, did you have any joy getting this to work ?

Unfortunately, no. We're actually considering moving away from .NET MAUI for this reason. We need this functionality. Sorry.
